# Adding new item to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a **ListView** and a **button**  **AddNewItem** and **two forms** both wrapped in two stack panels: **spanel1** and **spanel2**
when I select an item from the list, spanel1 shows data of the selected item
when I click on the button the form of spanel2 is empty

in the view model I have two properties: selectedItem and newItem
Problem:
if I fill data of the new item in the form of spanel2 and click Save (see Save command code) the NewItem property will not be changed

```
private void SaveItem(object obj)
    {
        if (this.selectedItem != null)
        {
            this.item.EditAsync(this.selectedItem );

        }
        else 
        {
            this.ietm.InsertAsync(this.NewItem);
        }

        this.LoadData();
      }

private Item newItem;

    public Item NewItem
    {
        get
        {

            return this.newItem ?? new Item();
        }
        set
        {
            this.newItem = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("NewItem");
        }
    }

private Item selectedItem;

public Item SelectedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.selectedItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.selectedItem= value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

                }
            }
```

what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: @Jonh By adding a new item, the selectedItem is always null

Answer (score 1):

1) create a new button in XAML

2) create a new command in UserVM class(call it UpdateOrAddNew command) and associate it with the button using "Command" property.

See this for more information: How to bind WPF button to a command in ViewModelBase?

3) In your UpdateOrAddNew command handler, check if SelectedUser is null(then create new user) or if it's not null, update existing one.

To take car of the TextBox issue, you need to create a wrapper that holds always information.

Add this to your UserVM:

```
public User UserRecord
{
    get
    {
       if(userRecord == null)
         return userRecord = new User();
    }
    set
    {
        userRecord = value;
        onPropertyChanged("UserRecord");
    }
}
```

now you need to modify your TextBoxes to bind against UserRecord, instead of SelectedUser.

and modify your SelectedUser:

```
public User SelectedUser
{
    get { return selecteduser; }
    set
    {
        selecteduser = value;
        onPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");

        UserRecord = selecteduser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need **two** properties? Why not just one?

Comment: @Mike Eason. Please if you have a solution in the context of your question, explain it.